# Android SDK changes for notifications and alarm between Nougat and Android10

Tags: android, notifications, android-alarms, android-version

I want to know if there was any changes with either notifications or alarms in the Android SDK between Nougat and Android10.

I have an app that works on Nougat (API 25) but when I tested it on Android 10 (API 29) the notification it was set to send never came (The notification is sent by an alarm).

Note: When it should be sending my notification it sends a different apps notification (repeatedly).

Here is what I am currently using:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Reader.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification.BigTextStyle bigText = new Notification.BigTextStyle();
    bigText.bigText(Text);
    bigText.setSummaryText(sText);
    Notification.Builder NotificationBuilder;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context,"BN_ID");
    } else {
    NotificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    }
    Notification.Builder mBuilder = NotificationBuilder;
    
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nicon);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("title");
    mBuilder.setContentText(sText);
    mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: This answers this question. [Troubles getting Notification working on Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517025/troubles-getting-notification-working-on-android-10)

Answer (score 1):

As in version >= 8.0 there is an update for showing notification you have to define channel

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "mychannelid";
```

then channel id to your notification builder

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1")
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper channel formatting like this

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;

public class App extends Application {

    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannels();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_1_ID,
                    "Channel 1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel1.setDescription("This is channel 1");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
        }
    }
}
```

And add this class in manifest like this under application tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jeuxdevelopers.com.notifications">

    <application
        android:name=".App"
```

Now in your main activity

```
public void sendOnChannel1(View view) {
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, activityIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_one)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .build();
    //If the first param is same it will overwrite
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, notification);
}
```

This is the global variable

```
private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat;
```

Instantiate it like this in `onCreate()`

```
notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
```

Comment: it is still not working I tried @Majid Ali code but it is the same. Can I post my new code in a comment for you to see? or is that not allowed?

Comment: Yes, sure you can try.