# Troubles getting Notification working on Android 10

Tags: java, android, notifications

My code for a notification works on Android API 25, but when I tried it on Android 10 it didn't work. I received no errors, it just simply did nothing at all. I have been trying to figure it out for the last two months without success. I failed to find anything helpful online and have tried everything I could possibly think of, but nothing has worked. Please help and thanks in advance.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, bibleReader.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    

    Notification.BigTextStyle bigText = new Notification.BigTextStyle();
    bigText.bigText(by);
    bigText.setSummaryText(bv);
    
    Notification.Builder NotificationBuilder;
    
    // check Android API verson and do as needed
    
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context, "ID_BN");
    } else {
    NotificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    }
    Notification.Builder mBuilder = NotificationBuilder;
    
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nicon);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("A Word");
    mBuilder.setContentText(bv);
    mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setTicker("text");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);  (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    mBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
    }
    
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oreo and above device have you try after create notification channel like below. Please have a look and let me know anything missing.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "A Word", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(),CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nicon)
                            .setContentTitle("A Word")
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentText(bv)
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                            .build();
                    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Thank you all so much, now I see what I was doing wrong.  For the benefit of others I will post the full working code in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

this code work fine in any version of android.

> you can put this code to any brodcastresciver or some things like that (service , etc...)

```
Intent pIntent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
    mpIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, pIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("todo");

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );

    String channelId="channel_id";
    CharSequence name="channel_name";
    String descruption="description";
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel channel=new NotificationChannel(channelId,name,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription(descruption);
        NotificationManager notificationManager=context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }


    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .setBigContentTitle("Your Title");

    Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif_icon)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500})
              .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo))
                 .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                 .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentTitle("Your Title")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDeleteIntent(contentIntent)
                .setStyle(bStyle)
                .setContentIntent(mpIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat=NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(notificationId,notification);
```

` have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the others on this forum I was able to put together the below code. Thank you all so much!

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, bibleReader.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
     }
    
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    Notification.BigTextStyle bigText = new Notification.BigTextStyle();
    bigText.bigText(textHere);
    bigText.setSummaryText(textHere);
    
    Notification.Builder NotificationBuilder;
    
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context, "ID");
    } else {
    NotificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    }
    Notification.Builder mBuilder = NotificationBuilder;
    
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nicon);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("text");
    mBuilder.setContentText(textHere);
    mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    mBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
    }
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```